# How to solve dependency error in gatsby js?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I was following Gatsbyjs tutorial. (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-four/) Link here.

I typed the command in window terminal,

```
gatsby new tutorial-part-four https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world
cd tutorial-part-four

npm install gatsby-plugin-typography typography react-typography typography-theme-kirkham gatsby-plugin-emotion @emotion/react
```

But error has occurred with these messages,

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0" from gatsby-plugin-typography@3.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/gatsby-plugin-typography
npm ERR!     gatsby-plugin-typography@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (gatsby, react-dom)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-typography@0.16.19
npm ERR! node_modules/react-typography
npm ERR!   peer react-typography@"^0.16.1 || ^1.0.0-alpha.0" from gatsby-plugin-typography@3.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/gatsby-plugin-typography
npm ERR!     gatsby-plugin-typography@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-13T09_43_09_116Z-debug.log
```

I want to know how to solve these error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`react-typography` isn't ready for react 17, so you'll have to downgrade react into version 16 to use it.

Edit `package.json` and look for:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "react": "^17.0.1",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
  ...
},
```

change the version numbers to `16.14.0`

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "react": "^16.14.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
  ...
},
```

Save it and then remove all the files from `node_modules/`

`rm -Rf node_modules`

Finally, just reinstall everything using the command:

`npm install`

Continue with your command...

`npm install gatsby-plugin-typography typography react-typography typography-theme-kirkham gatsby-plugin-emotion @emotion/react`

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is coming from `npm` versions

Try with adding `--legacy-peer-deps`  option in npm install command

```
npm install gatsby-plugin-typography typography react-typography typography-theme-kirkham gatsby-plugin-emotion @emotion/react --legacy-peer-deps
```

or try after cleaning the npm by using below command

```
npm cache clean --force
```